# Fix MySQL query syntax error (LIMIT)

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'tbl_content'

When I run the following query I can see 11 records/data

```
SELECT ContentID, CategoryID, Home, Inner
FROM tbl_content
WHERE CategoryID = 1 AND Inner = 2
ORDER BY ContentID DESC
```

When I run the following query I can see first 4 records/data

```
SELECT ContentID, CategoryID, Home, Inner
FROM tbl_content
WHERE CategoryID = 1 AND Inner = 2
ORDER BY ContentID DESC LIMIT 7, 10
```

I want to update value of the remaining first 4 records/data. But unfortunately it is generating error.

```
UPDATE tbl_content
SET Inner = 1
WHERE CategoryID = 1 AND Inner = 2
ORDER BY ContentID DESC LIMIT 7, 10
```

Can anyone kindly give any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
UPDATE tbl_content SET Inner=1 WHERE id IN(SELECT ContentId FROM (SELECT ContentID, CategoryID, Home, Inner FROM tbl_content WHERE CategoryID=1 AND Inner=2 ORDER BY ContentID DESC LIMIT 7, 10));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try uisng an IN clause for subslect with limit

```
UPDATE tbl_content SET Inner=1 
WHERE CategoryID=1 AND Inner=2 
AND ContentID  IN ( 
 select contentID from (
  select ContentID  
  from  tbl_content 
  order by ORDER BY ContentID DESC LIMIT 7, 10 ) t

)
```

or a join

```
UPDATE tbl_content c 
INNER JOIN (
  select ContentID  
  from  tbl_content 
  order by ORDER BY ContentID DESC LIMIT 7, 10 
) t  on t.ContentID = c.ContentID
SET c.Inner=1 
WHERE c.CategoryID=1 AND c.Inner=2
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  .. probably  you are right  .. anyway  wrapped the subquery for avoid problem in the IN sample  .. thanks

Comment: Your first solution updates records from number 5th to 8th. And your last solution updates first 4 records. But I wanted to keep first 7 records intact and change last /rest of the records.